# Internal Url Redirection to new urls as website redesigned

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Old URL: https://www.abc.in/browse/handpiece
New Url: https://www.abc.in/denrtal-handpiece

When I tried following:

Redirect 301 /browse/handpiece https://www.abc.in/denrtal-handpiece

this redirect on - [https://www.abc.in/denrtal-handpiece?*route*=product/handpiece](https://www.abc.in/denrtal-handpiece?_route_=product/handpiece)

How to fix it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

redirectMatch 301 ^/browse/handpiece$ /denrtal-handpiece

Comment: Still url redirecting with  ?route=product/handpiece